# Intersection of plus/minus cells in Bialynicki-Birula decomposition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, morse-theory

Let $X$ be a projective variety endowed with an algebraic $\mathbb{C}^*$-action. Assume the fixed point set $W$ is discrete. Then we have two cell decompositions of $X$:

$X = \bigsqcup_{w\in W} C_w$ and $X = \bigsqcup_{w\in W} C^w$,

where

$C_w = \{x\in X | \lim_{t\to 0} t\cdot x = w \}$ and $C^w=\{x\in X | \lim_{t\to \infty} t\cdot x = w\}$,

the so-called plus and minus Bialynicki-Birula decomposition. Assume that both of these decompositions are in fact stratifications (although this latter bit may be irrelevant to the question).

My (slightly vague) question: Are there any general results about the structure of the intersections $C_w \cap C^v$? When non-empty are they smooth in general? My favorite example of the flag variety, these are smooth (I think). It would make me extremely happy if someone could point me to towards a general description of the cohomology groups of these intersections?

Note: In the special situation of flag varieties I am familiar with Deodhar's and Curtis' results describing these intersections. But, unless I am missing something, their results don't help in describing the cohomology groups.

Comment: @RV: It would probably be helpful to point to one particular paper by B-B which is most relevant to your question, since he wrote a lot of papers involving torus actions on varieties.   Do you have his *Annals* paper especially in mind?

Comment: They are indeed smooth on the flag variety -- this is essentially Kleiman transversality. Also, I think assuming that the two are transverse would imply your stratification assumption. Unfortunately this is quite rare.

Comment: @Jim: To be honest my extremely limited understanding of the B-B result comes from the Morse theoretic description of it in section 2.4 of Chriss and Ginzburg's book on Complex Geometry and Representation Theory. However, I did originally look at the B-B Annals paper to see if my question was answered there. However, from my skimming of it I did not find anything helpful. But I do find that paper a tough read so could have easily missed a key point.

Comment: @Allen: Thanks! Kleiman transversality is what I had in mind for smoothness on the flag variety. Good to know I was not completely off! However, I don't see how transversality would imply the stratification assumption in general. Could you elaborate? On the other hand I am also perfectly happy just assuming that it is a stratification.

Comment: In Bialynicki-Birula's 1976 paper in the *Bulletin de l'academie polonaise des sciences, série des sciences math., astr. et phys*, Theorem 5 states that a transversality condition ensures that the decomposition is a stratification, and there is also a proof.