# Reductions of a system of equations at various primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $f_1, \dots, f_n$ be a finite set of polynomials in the polynomial ring $Z[x_1, \dots, x_m]$. At a prime $p$, let $N_p$ be the number of solutions $x=(x_1, \dots, x_m)\in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^m$ to the system $$f_1(x)=f_2(x)=f_3(x)=\dots=f_n(x)=0$$ (with coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_m\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$).

As a function of $p$, are there any conditions (on the set of polynomials $f_1, \dots, f_n$) under which $N_p$ is a polynomial in $p$ for large enough values (or perhaps all values) of $p$?

The system that I'd like this to be true for (all primes $p$) is
$$f_1=(a_3^2-a_3)-a_2(c_1^2-c_1)-a_1(b_1^2-b_1)=0$$
$$f_2=(a_4^2-a_4)-a_2(c_2^2-c_2)-a_1(b_2^2-b_2)=0$$
$$f_3=a_3a_4-a_2c_1c_2-a_1b_1b_2=0 $$

in the $8$ variable polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[a_1,a_2, a_3,a_4, b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2]$.

Computations done for $p\leq 19$ lead us to expect $N_p=p^5 + 12 p^4 - 20 p^3 + 30 p^2 - 10 p$.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that zeta functions are for, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I suppose that the zeta function one usually considered is that attahced to a variety over a fixed finite field, and it measures the variation of N_q where q runs over all powers of a fixed prime p, so maybe if one were to ask a similar question but count number of solutions in $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ and let r go to infinity, perhaps the zeta function would play a role. I guess the zeta function of interest in this context when p varies would be associated to the scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$, however, I'm not well aware of what is known about their Euler product factorization.

Comment: The Hasse-Weil zeta function might be the one David Loeffler was alluding to, although, from experience, if you have a conjectural polynomial formula it suggests there is a nice parameterization for the solutions that can be found by hand. It seems you have 8 variables (not 7) which suggests the count should grow like $p^{8-3}$ and not like $p^4$, so I am confused.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167934/varieties-with-polynomial-point-count-and-no-odd-cohomology

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Thank you for the link, once again this seems to concern varieties over a fixed finite field (i.e., p fixed) and q ranging over the powers of p. In this setting, the variety has polynomial point count if and only if there is no non-vanishing odd cohomology. If there is polynomial point count then the zeta function (over $\mathbb{F}_p$) is the reciprocal of a polynomial. Now, I don't understand how this means that there should be any relationship exhibited by the local Euler factors in the Hasse-Weil zeta function at different primes $p$ and $\ell$.

Comment: If the variety has no odd cohomology and the even cohomology groups are all spanned by algebraic cycles in characteristic zero, you will have polynomial count for varying $p$ as well.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch How does one compute the relevant cohomology groups in this example and check this sort of condition?

Comment: I don't know if there is a general algorithm. In your case, you can eliminate $a_4$ using $f_3$ and $a_2$ using $f_1$ and end up with one equation in the remaining $6$ variables. I think this is quadratic in $c_2$, so you have a conic bundle over a projective space so you can look at the locus where the discriminant vanishes and reduce dimension and hope that you can continue from that.

Comment: Similar to Felipe Voloch's suggestion: Use $f_1$ and $f_2$ to solve for $a_1$ and $a_2$. Then $f_3$ becomes a conic in $a_3$ and $a_4$. So things reduce to handle certain degenerate situations, e.g. where the denominator of the expressions for $a_1$ and $a_2$ vanishes, or where the conic in $a_3$ and $a_4$ is degenerate. Also, one has to take care of points at infinity of the conic.